# Importing Requests causes print() to print twice

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm running Python 3.6.3 on Windows 10 and installed Requests via pip.

```
#!python
import requests
print('Hello')
```

Results in "Hello" printing twice on PowerShell as well as Command Prompt. When I don't import requests, print works as expected.

Launching Python and importing from the prompt however causes no issue.

Comment: Is the file you are running named `requests`, per chance?

Comment: No, it's named html.py

Comment: try a less "standard" name.

Comment: It's the filename. I'll post a screenshot.

Comment: rename to "foo.py" and retry

Comment: I had the same issue.  Realized I had to rename my Python script file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening is the `requests` library is importing a file named `html`. Since your file is also named `html.py` and is on the import path it is loaded twice.

Use the convention

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("HI")
```

to avoid this.

See this question for more details: [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: Thanks! As you can see I'm new to Python so i'm fumbling a bit.

Comment: Happy to. You might have to rename your file anyway if the `requests` module claims something under `html` is missing. But that's another error for later on. Happy hacking.

Comment: never use "smart" & generic names like that. You may stumble on already existing module names.

Answer (score 0):

There must be something in the requests library that hiccups on a filename named "html.py".

[image]